# Changing AppWidget's background dynamically with a 9 patch drawable

Tags: android, background-image, drawable, android-appwidget, nine-patch

There is no `setBackground()` method in the `RemoteViews` class, so I've used the following workaround:

1. Created a `FrameLayout` for my app widget with an `ImageView` as the background view.
2. Changed the `ImageView` image using `setImageViewResource()` method.

Unfortunately, when it comes to 9-patch drawables this method does not work. Also when an `ImageView`'s `android:src` attribute points to 9-patch - it doesn't work too. Is there any way to change the `AppWidget`'s background image programatically using a 9-patch drawable? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Settings the 9-patch as initial background in the XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/small_widget_layout_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_lime" />
```

When I use `android:src="@drawable/background_lime"` it doesn't stretch the image properly, this code works fine. And the code to change the background from the `AppWidgetProvider` `onUpdate` method:

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.small_widget_layout_bg,
                    R.drawable.backgroung_lime);
```

This does not stretch the image as a 9-patch.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'?

Comment: @ReubenScratton, The 9-patch isn't stretched properly, it's just centered and stretched awfully like a simple PNG drawable.

Comment: Are you certain your 9-patch is valid? i.e. draws properly in a normal, in-process context.  I'm pretty sure I've done this without issue before...

Comment: @ReubenScratton, Yes, the 9-patch is absolutely valid. If I set as an initial background for the app widget in XML - it resizes perfectly.

Comment: Re "initial background", you mean you set it as android:src and it works fine, just not when you change the exact same property via RemoteViews?

Comment: @ReubenScratton, Actually, it doesn't work either when I set it as android:src, but when it's set as android:background - it works fine.

Comment: it sounds like it doesnT recognize it as a 9-patch actually, could you post how you set it in the codebehind?

Comment: @Zortkun, Yes, I'll update my question.

Comment: Isn't that a general ImageView thing? What happens if you set the ImageView scaleType to "fitXY"?

Comment: @ReubenScratton, I've tried it and it works perfectly! Thanks! Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad this was a simple one. Cheers @Egor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer was diagnosed in the above comments...

`RemoteView` doesn't allow access to `View.setBackground()`, so your workaround of using the `android:src` property of an `ImageView` is good, providing that `the android:scaleType` property is set to **fitXY**.

`ImageView` won't stretch it's foreground image unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 4):

Please ignore if u find this trivial or irrelevant, but canT you try (assuming you are dealing with *widgets*):

- Declaring different layouts (`xml`)for your `widget`.
- Change the `remoteView'`s source (`layout.id`) instead of trying to make alterations to the selected layout.

*AFAIK*, this is the most common approach to solving such problems. This is not perfect for two simple things I could note myself:

- *What do you do if you have n different "states" / "views" in your widget?*

But as long as your 9-patch files are also static resources, *n* is painful but still theoretically manageable.

- *It s tedious to keep track of the changes in these parallel files.*

I'd also love to find an easy way for this one...

This approach may not be an option for you also because it is basically the hard way. But it s an option nonetheless.

---

**Suggestion #2**

Have you tried using the method?

`public void setInt (int viewId, String methodName, int value)`

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.viewid, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.backgroung_lime);
```

From another question: [Change remoteView ImageView background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333774/change-remoteview-imageview-background)

Comment: This question is concerned with [App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html); Home Screen 'plugins'.  `remoteViews` is not the OP's own class.

Comment: yeah i guess. Did i make it sound like it was a custom class? cos it wasnT the intention. i ll edit.

Comment: @Zortkun u deserve +1 up vote for your suggestion #2. it solved my problem like a charm :)