# How to change the background's color of an ImageView in RemoteViews without changing its shape?

Tags: java, android, imageview, remoteview

I would like to know if I can change the background's color of an ImageView in RemoteViews without changing its shape and also without changing the color of its src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Change remoteView ImageView background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333774/change-remoteview-imageview-background)